# Public server with nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to make my development server public.

I have a static ip address from my ISP.

As usually I have a router and server connected to that router. In the router's settings I've set the forwarding port to 3000, so if somebody will try `my_public_ip_address:3000`, it will be forwarded to my local server.

Nginx config file:

```
upstream app {
  server points_to_app_on_server;
}

server {
  listen 3000;
  server_name <what is name should be here?>;

  ...
}
```

Is it possible to configure nginx to make my server public?
Also is it possible to make it accessible from local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it can. If your server's ports are exposed to the public, then anyone can connect to your running services like nginx.

With the config file you have, listening on port 3000, and if your `public.ip:3000` is forwarded (or NATed) to `local.ip:3000`, then anyone can access your nginx server by connecting to `your.public.ip:3000`. Anyone in your local network can also access your server, either by `your.local.ip:3000` or `your.public.ip:3000` (assuming you have internet connection in your local network).

Comment: What about `server_name`? Where it should point to, the local ip address or public address?

Comment: @megas You specify different `server_name` only if you have DNS services. Otherwise, it doesn't matter what you specify. You can use your local IP address.